# Issue with slideToggle in JQuery, not sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have been practicing coding this website for a while, it is just a small thing and I have been enjoying it. I have had an issue with trying to make a feature on my nav bar were a green div slides down when the nav option is hovered over. I have posted a question about this same thing recently, and got great answers, but even after a did what the answers were telling me to it still would not work. I figure it is because I didn't give enough of my code, thats why I have posted most of my code here, which I am very sorry for. Please help, I have been putting off this issue for a while but now I just want to fix it so I can move on to more interactive stuff with this website. Thank you for your time.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cambay' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Magra' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mallanna' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramabhadra' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dhurjati' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row" id="row0">
<!--NAVIGATION ANIMATIONS-->
    <ul id="nav_animations">
        <li class="nav_square home_square" id="greenHome"></li>
        <li class="nav_square specials_square" id="greenSpecials"></li>
        <li class="nav_square jobs_square" id="greenJobs"></li>
        <li class="nav_square league_square" id="greenLeague"></li>
        <li class="nav_square contact_square" id="greenContact"></li>
    <!--POSITION SAFE NAV SQUARES-->
        <li class="nav_square safe_nav_squares home_square" id="home_safe"></li>
        <li class="nav_square safe_nav_squares specials_square" id="specials_safe"></li>
        <li class="nav_square safe_nav_squares jobs_square" id="jobs_safe"></li>
        <li class="nav_square safe_nav_squares league_square" id="league_safe"></li>
        <li class="nav_square safe_nav_squares contact_square" id="contact_safe"></li>
    </ul>
<!--END OF NAV ANIMATION-->
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li class="navlistitems" id="home">Home</li>
            <li class="navlistitems" id="specials">Specials</li>
            <li class="navlistitems" id="jobs">Jobs</li>
            <li class="navlistitems" id="league">League Bowling</li>
            <li class="navlistitems" id="contact">Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="row1">
        <h1 class="1Headers" id="hodagLanes">Hodag Lanes</h1>
        <h3 class="3Headers" id="location">Located in Rhinelander Wisconsin</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="row2">
        <ul id="offer_bottom">
            <li class="offeritem" id="spinitem">
                <h3 class="3Headers" id="spin2win">Spin to Win Bowling 9:00-11:00</h3>
                <p id="spinp">Come play spin to win! You have the chance to win amazing prizes, including a free game of bowling!</p>
                <img src="http://www.socialbungy.com/img/home/spin-2-win-icon.png" id="spinimg">
            </li>
            <li class="offeritem" id="couponitem">
                <h3 class="3Headers" id="coupons">Coupons</h3>
                <p id="couponp">Free coupons for bowling and other local businesses! Download your free coupons today!
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsGCo_CzBamZcAV3uQzTLF8KKlwv4yp1Z5ZQkA1Wd4qzTFNJAN" id="couponimg">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
}
#nav_animations {
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    bottom:13px;
}
#greenHome {
    display:none;
}
.nav_square {
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:15px;
    z-index:22;
    position:relative;
}
.home_square {
    position:relative;
    left:84px;
}
.specials_square {
    position:relative;
    left:310px;
    bottom:16px;
}
.jobs_square {
    position:relative;
    left:530px;
    bottom:31px;
}
.league_square {
    position:relative;
    left:790px;
    bottom:47px;
}
.contact_square {
    position:relative;
    left:1113px;
    bottom:62px;
}
.safe_nav_squares {
    background-color:black;
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
    bottom:75px;
}
#specials_safe {
    bottom:91px;
}
#jobs_safe {
    bottom:106px;
}
#league_safe {
    bottom:122px;
}
#contact_safe {
    bottom:137px;
}
#row0 {
    position:relative;
    bottom:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
}
#navlist {
    display:inline;
    font-family: 'Dhurjati', sans-serif;
    font-size:45px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:186px;
}
.navlistitems {
    display:inline;
    padding:50px;
    color:white;
}
#home:hover {
    color:#BABABA;
    text-shadow:0px 2px 3px green;
}
#specials:hover {
    color:#BABABA;
    text-shadow:0px 2px 3px green;
}
#jobs:hover {
    color:#BABABA;
    text-shadow:0px 2px 3px green;
}
#league:hover {
    color:#BABABA;
    text-shadow:0px 2px 3px green;
}
#contact {
    font-size:40px;
}
#contact:hover {
    color:#BABABA;
    text-shadow:0px 2px 3px green;
}
#row1 {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-image:url("http://lakewoodlanes.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/family_Bowling.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
}
#hodaglanes {
    font-family: 'Mallanna', sans-serif;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:370px;
    color:white;
    font-size:70px;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
#location {
    font-family: 'Magra', sans-serif;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:417px;
    color:#D4D4D4;
    font-size:30px;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
#row2 {
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
}
#spin2win {
    color:#6B6B6B;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    position:relative;
    left:13px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white
}
#spinimg {
    border:1px solid black
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
}
#spinp {
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Cambay', sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:287px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid gray;
    width:389px;
}
#couponp {
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Cambay', sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-295px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid gray;
    width:400px;
}
#coupons {
    color:#6B6B6B;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    position:relative;
    left:149px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white
}
#couponimg {
    height:300px;
}
#offer_bottom {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
}
.offeritem {
    display:inline;
}
#couponitem {
    position:relative;
    left:550px;
    bottom:440px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#home').hover(function(){
        $('#greenHome').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Like I said I am extremely sorry for overloading all of this code on you, I am aware it is against the rules but I honestly do not know what to do, I have spent hours trying to debug my code.
 **FYI the css code is most likely not the problem so you probably do not have to look at that unless you can't find it in the html or javascript.**

Comment: What do you mean by "not sliding"? Is it not sliding the way you want it? It is sliding every single time you hover, or selectively? Do you have any error messages in the console log?

Comment: It is not sliding at all. And I just checked the console. There is nothing that directly appeals to the issue at hand.

Comment: did you wrap you javascript in `$(document).ready(function() {})`?